# Do "When does your school/work start and finish?" refer to to a long school/work process or just everyday school/work?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

According to my research

-"**School**" refers to a physical school or the time spent there

-"**Work**" refers to a physical working place or the time spent there

When do people say "**when does your school/work start and finish?**", do they refer to everyday school/work?

If they do, then I will answer "**My school/work starts at 7am and finishes at 5 pm**".

But, let say a student is on summer vacation and he begins to go to school at the beginning of March next year and the learning process ends at the beginning of December next year. Then, **does this conversation make sense?**

> A: When does your school start?
>
> B: My school starts at the beginning of
> March next year and finishes at the beginning of
> December next year. (This refers to a long school process , not everyday
> one)

Another example, say a contract worker is still at home waiting for his work which begins  at the beginning of March next year and the working process ends at the beginning of December next year. Then, **does this conversation make sense?**

> A: When does your work start?
>
> B: My work starts at the beginning of
> March next year and finishes at the beginning of
> December next year. (This refers to a long work process , not everyday
> one)

Comment: They all make sense, and the context will resolve any ambiguity. If not, the hearer will ask a question to request the exact meaning.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, Your answer is similar to Chatgpt

Comment: You can say "school day" or "school session/year" or something similar if you're worried about ambiguity.

Comment: @Tom - is that good or bad?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it may mean either,depending on the context of your discussion.   However, to avoid ambiguity, you'd better use it for daily school hours.  As for the other, you may say "my school year or academic year starts .....and finishes.....

Comment: Or "Next term (division of a school year) starts on..." - "My (work) contract starts on..."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).